# Using foreach loop to retrieve records and insert into table if not found

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

I have a session that is storing area codes.  What I want to do is loop through each of those area codes and see if there are any records in the MySql database.  If there are NO records, then I want to insert that area code into a different table.

I've created a loop to do this, but it isn't inserting new records.  Maybe my use of !isset is wrong?   If I'm not making sense, here is my code:

```
//Start
//Set Variables.

$today = date("Y-m-d");
$getAreaCodes = $_SESSION['area_code'];

    // Start Foreach Loop.  For every area code in session, get it's area code from the zip_zip table

    foreach($getAreaCodes as $value) {

        mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
        $query_getAC = sprintf("SELECT area_code FROM zip_zip WHERE area_code = $value", GetSQLValueString($colname_getAC, "text"));
        $getAC = mysql_query($query_getAC, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_getAC = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAC);
        $totalRows_getAC = mysql_num_rows($getAC);

            // If it does NOT exist, insert it into zip_areacodes.
            if (!isset($row_getAC)){
                $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO zip_areacodes (area_code, date, type) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                    GetSQLValueString($value, "text"),
                    GetSQLValueString($today, "text"),
                    GetSQLValueString("bad", "text"));                          
                    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
            }
    }

mysql_free_result($getAC);

//Moving to another page

header("Location: confirm.php");
exit;
```

Comment: you should be able to do it in 2 ways: empty($row_getAC) or $totalRows_getAC == 0. should have the same effect after your select statement. (both instead of your !isset($row_getAC))

Comment: Yes that worked.  I used empty.  I appreciate your help!  If it would have returned NULL, would empty still work?  (For other uses)

Comment: Also, since this was answered with a comment, how do I close this question and make your answer the right one?

Comment: my bad, wrote too fast :). check my answer below. greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SherwoodPro

you should be able to do it in 2 ways: `empty($row_getAC)` or `$totalRows_getAC == 0`. should have the same effect after your select statement. (both instead of your `!isset($row_getAC)`)

if you get a NULL, php will interpretate it still as empty. [isset vs empty](http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/) check the lower table as reference.

greetings

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  I appreciate the link, that helps clear things up a lot and will prove useful to keep in mind.